# Is there a way where I don't have to fine tune my margins and paddings on my onepager?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, anchor

I had a problem where the buttons didn't scroll me to the top of the anchor and would instead scroll too far into the section (that was because my navbar is fixed and is overlapping the section).

I fixed it with margins and paddings but I feel like there is a much better and more simple solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/2n9b0ohp/76/

I experimented around for a few hours but couldn't really find the perfect solution, there was always something wrong and not working.

```
$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});



//
```

```
/* MAIN */

/* SECTION HOME */
#home {
  height: 853px !important;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -128px;
  padding-top: 128px;
}

#homebild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION WIR-UEBER-UNS */
#wir-ueber-uns {
  height: 853px !important;
  display: flex;
  top: -208px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#wir-ueber-unsbild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION AKTIONEN */
#aktionen {
  height: 853px !important;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: -288px;
  z-index: -3;
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#aktionenbild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION TERMINVEREINBARUNG */
#terminvereinbarung {
  height: 853px !important;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: -368px;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -4;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

#terminvereinbarungbild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION INFOS */
#infos {
  height: 772px !important;
  width: 1280px;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: -448px;
  z-index: -5;
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

/* MAIN ENDE */
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>OptikTack</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="body">
        <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <nav id="navbar">
          <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
          <a href="#home" id="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/przxCGcx/Logo.png" class="logo"></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#wir-ueber-uns">Wir über uns</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#infos">Infos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- NAVIGATION ENDE -->
        <!-- MAIN -->
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <!-- home section -->
        <section id="home" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tgk5cWmx/Bild-1.jpg" alt="Frau" id="homebild" width="1280px">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- home section ende -->
        <!-- wir-ueber-uns section -->
        <section id="wir-ueber-uns" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FH6RSxbF/Bild-2.jpg" width="1280px" id="wir-ueber-unsbild">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- wir-ueber-uns section ende -->
        <!-- aktionen section -->
        <div id="reference"></div>
        <section id="aktionen" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/k5P0L6qF/Bild-5.jpg" width="1280px" id="aktionenbild">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- aktionen section ende -->
        <!-- terminvereinbarung section -->
        <section id="terminvereinbarung" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/6q8b8tBp/Bild-9.jpg" width="1280px" id="terminverinbarungbild">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- terminvereinbarung section ende -->
        <!-- infos section -->
        <section id="infos" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 5</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- infos section ende -->
        <!-- MAIN ENDE -->
```

Comment: Side note: use a simple/minimalistic framework for a basic setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to all these anchors which adds a pseudo-element to them having the following settings:

```
.your_anchor_class::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -80px; 
  height: 80px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The `80px` and `-80px` values will have to be adjusted according to the height of your fixed header, but this will  create pseudo elements which are as high as the header and will then be *behind*  then header, aligning their according "main" elements *under*  the header.

ADDITION/EDIT after seeing your Fiddle (edited one more time after comment):

I didn't know before that you don't "jump" to the anchor positions directly, but there's an animated scrolling script which scrolls to those anchors, which has to be handled differently, i.e. by changing the script.

So I only changed one little thing in your Javascript (at the bottom of the HTML code): I added " - 80 " to the `animate` function, which adds (or rather subtracts) an offset of 80px to the position which the script animation scrolls. (only exception: if the link anchor is `#home`, there is no offset, since in this case the page has to scroll up all the way, that's what the if/else is for):

```
<!-- Smooth Scroll -->
<script>
  $('a').click(function() {
  var scrollziel = $(this).attr('href');
    if(scrollziel == '#home') {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 500);
      return false;
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 80
      }, 500);
      return false;
    }
  });
</script>
<!-- Smooth Scroll Ende -->
```

This seems to fix it, see my version of your fiddle, with only that one little difference: https://jsfiddle.net/c1gjybtf/

Comment: I added that but now there are gaps between my sections and it somehow didn't work for **Terminvereinbarung**

```

Comment: You still have `top: -80px` and `padding-top: 80px` in your main elements (should be erased)

Comment: But I grayed them out with /* */ I thought it would ignore them when I gray them out

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't notice that before. But you commented out the *whole*  CSS rule/s for these elements that way - this probably destroys your layout (?) You should only comment out the `top: -80px` and `padding-top: 80px`for testing this.

Comment: I commented out the `top: -80px` and `padding-top: 80px` now and the navbar still scrolls too far. Here's my [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/017w82rb/285/)

Comment: It seems be working great so thank you a lot for your help! Since my navbar at the start of scrolling down is 128px in height it seems to not be scrolling up enough when you click on **home**

Comment: Please note: I changed the code in the question once more and added another fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is working like a charm. Now when I scroll up manually the underline on home disappears. Any reason why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
  font-family: "Saira", "Roboto",  Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and changed the `top:` to -80px on every section (since my navbar is 80px in height)

This made it a bit more simple